# Static Image in Product Collection List - Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am trying to add a static image connected to a metafield in my collection template to where the 3rd and 6th product card would normally go for an "internal campaign" type card.

This is for the pipeline theme.

Looking for some code to insert